# Allow only one (approve/reject) checkbox to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

updated:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="chkbox_checked_uncheked.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Ediable_Repeater.chkbox_checked_uncheked" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#C1All').click(function () {
                debugger
                $('.col1').attr("checked", $('#C1All').attr("checked"));
                $('.col2').removeAttr("checked");
                $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
            });

            $('#C2All').click(function () {
                debugger
                $('.col2').attr("checked", $('#C2All').attr("checked"));
                $('.col1').removeAttr("checked");
                $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
            });

            $('.col1').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    debugger
                    var coresId = id.replace('C1', 'C2');
                    $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                });
            });

            $('.col2').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var coresId = id.replace('C2', 'C1');
                    debugger
                    $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                });
            });
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C1All" runat="server" class="col1" Text="approve all" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C2All" runat="server"  class="col2" Text="Reject all" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C101" runat="server" class="col1" Text="john 0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C201" runat="server"  class="col2" Text="john 0" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C102" runat="server" class="col1" Text="john 1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C202" runat="server"  class="col2" Text="john all" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C103" runat="server" class="col1" Text="john 2" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="C203" runat="server"  class="col2" Text="John 2" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i have a two columns (approve all/reject all) how can i restrict the user to allow only one checkbox of each?

here is the output of the screen:

[image]

i have tried something like this but did not work:

```
 function SelectApproveAllCheckboxes(chk, selector) 
    {     
         $('#<%=gv.ClientID%>').find(selector + " input:checkbox").each(function () 
        {                    
              $(this).prop("checked", $(chk).prop("checked"));     
         }); 
    } 
function SelectRejectAllCheckboxes(chk, selector) 
{     
     $('#<%=gv.ClientID%>').find(selector + " input:checkbox").each(function () 
    {                    
          $(this).prop("checked", $(chk).prop("checked"));     
     }); 
}  

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectApproveAllCheckboxes(this, '.approve)" />     
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll1" runat="server" onclick="SelectRejectAllCheckboxes(this, '.reject)" />
```

Comment: I knew it was an image... but couldn't resist trying to click a checkbox.

Comment: Is it out of the question to use radio buttons?

Comment: i update my question, yes but client would like to have checkbox and i have already thought of using radio button

Comment: just curious; why do you need the select all option on top of each column if you are to restrict one option from each column?

Comment: i might have 100 rows + pages so user dont have to go one by one to approve or reject .... and for example i just create 4 rows

Comment: OK. Just to be clear, so based on your image if I take John 0 you want to only select John 0 either from first column or second column (bot not both at once). But still you can select more than one option from the same column. Like John 0, John 1 from column1. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK based on your answer to my questions on the comments section to your question, here is a working solution. I've used a HTML table with static controls; but you should be able to apply the concepts.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C1All" />Approve All</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C2All" />Reject All</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C101" class="col1" />John 0</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C201" class="col2" />John 0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C102" class="col1" />John 1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C202" class="col2" />John 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C103" class="col1" />John 2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="C203" class="col2" />John 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#C1All').click(function () {
                $('.col1').attr("checked", $('#C1All').attr("checked"));
                $('.col2').removeAttr("checked");
                $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
            });

            $('#C2All').click(function () {
                $('.col2').attr("checked", $('#C2All').attr("checked"));
                $('.col1').removeAttr("checked");
                $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
            });

            $('.col1').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var coresId = id.replace('C1', 'C2');
                    $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                });
            });

            $('.col2').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var coresId = id.replace('C2', 'C1');
                    $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDITED**

since in asp.net checkboxes are nested within the span tags make use of this jquery instead of the previous one.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#C1All').click(function () {
                $('.col1 > input').attr("checked", $('#C1All').attr("checked"));
                $('.col2 > input').removeAttr("checked");
                $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
            });

            $('#C2All').click(function () {
                $('.col2 > input').attr("checked", $('#C2All').attr("checked"));
                $('.col1 > input').removeAttr("checked");
                $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
            });

            $('.col1').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var id = $("input", this).attr('id');
                    var coresId = id.replace('C1', 'C2');
                    $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                });
            });

            $('.col2').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var id = $("input", this).attr('id');
                    var coresId = id.replace('C2', 'C1');
                    $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: working fine as expected with html control so i started changing transforming from html controls to asp.net when i run the page and select approve all checkbox then i got this error message `$(this).attr('id') is undefined` -

Comment: updated my question, you can copy and paste the updated code i have posted, and test out and i am looking at the error, if you find then post it.

Comment: @AbuHamzah check my edited answer. Now it should work. Some issue with the input selectors as checkboxes are rendered as part of the span tags.

Comment: IMPORTANT: remove class attributes for C1All, C2All. in other words the header checkboxes SHOULD NOT have the class="col1", class="col2". remove them

Comment: no problem :). If it answers your question please mark it as the answer. thanks

Comment: working as i was expecting but one minor issue when i clicked on check all then it checks all the checkboxes but its also uncheck the header checkbox. its almost there...

Comment: did you not forgot to remove the class names on the header checkboxes? that should fix it

Comment: prashanth t: i have posted the question here and its related to the question i have asked you and now i am using gridview and does not seems to work please have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607199/how-to-make-this-jquery-code-works-with-gridview-control-asp-net#comment13746483_10607199

Answer (score 4):

dont use checkboxes use radio buttons instead, they are designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using radio buttons. You can still have a "Select All" checkbox, and could have it disable the radio buttons when checked.

If you must use check boxes, you could simply overwrite the default click (check) action to first uncheck all of the other boxes. It should be pretty basic javascript with or without a library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> > ```
> > $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
> >    $('input:checked').removeAttr('checked');
> >    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
> > });
> > ```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you use radio button prolly you won't get the select all feature.

You can give all of the checkboxes in the group the same class and do something like this to uncheck them all using JQuery, while checking or unchecking the one that was clicked:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function{
// save the original checked state of the one we're clicking:
 var checked = $(this).attr('checked'); 
 $('.checkbox').attr('checked', false); // uncheck all of the boxes
 $(this).attr('checked', !checked); // invert the original state
});
```

But the better choice would probably be to use a radio button control with a "none of the above" option. That way you can do validation (did that answer the question at all?)