# How to make this jQuery code works with GridView control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

**edit:**
What is not working:- i have a two columns (approve all/reject all) how can i restrict the user to allow only one checkbox of each? the below code works if you dont use the gridview....

i have asked this question here ([Allow only one (approve/reject) checkbox to be checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560012/allow-only-one-approve-reject-checkbox-to-be-checked) ) and its working as expected **only** if i have asp.net control meaning without using the gridview control and now i'm in a situation where i have to use the gridview control and seems my code does not work... i have maintained the same class names. any help?

here is my .aspx code with gridview:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#C1All').click(function () { debugger
                 $('.col1 > input').attr("checked", $('#C1All').attr("checked"));
                 $('.col2 > input').removeAttr("checked");
                 $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
             });

             $('#C2All').click(function () { debugger
                 $('.col2 > input').attr("checked", $('#C2All').attr("checked"));
                 $('.col1 > input').removeAttr("checked");
                 $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
             });

             $('.col1').each(function () { 
                 $(this).click(function () { debugger
                     var id = $("input", this).attr('id');
                     var coresId = id.replace('C1', 'C2');
                     $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                     $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                     $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                 });
             });

             $('.col2').each(function () { 
                 $(this).click(function () {debugger
                     var id = $("input", this).attr('id');
                     var coresId = id.replace('C2', 'C1');
                     $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
                     $('#C1All').removeAttr("checked");
                     $('#C2All').removeAttr("checked");
                 });
             });
         });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"
        OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Approve<br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="C1All" runat="server"  />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate   >
                <asp:CheckBox CssClass="col1" ID="chkApprove" runat="server"  >
                </asp:CheckBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reject" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="180px">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Reject<br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="C2All"  runat="server"  />
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="drpPaymentMethod" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Please select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Month</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">At End</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">At Travel</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <div class="selectReason">
                    <asp:CheckBox CssClass="col2"  ID="chkReject" runat="server" >
                    </asp:CheckBox>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="drpPaymentMethod" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Please select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Month</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">At End</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">At Travel</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="FirstName"
                SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="LastName"
                SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:TemplateField>

            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error message? Are you getting unexpected behavior?

Comment: Looking at your previous question it looks like Stuart [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10560027/275643) made a good suggestion that you use a radio buttons instead of checkboxes. Is that not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all to do with how controls are rendered to the browser. So based on that you will need to modify the jQuery element selectors. In the case with your `GridView` what is happening is that instead of `C1All` and `C2All` it is now `gv_C1All` and `gv_C2All`. In the case of checkboxes, instead of replacing `C1` with `C2` and vise versa, this time you will need to replace the word `Approve` with `Reject` and vise versa. Here is the modified jQuery. Now it should work.

I would suggest you to have a look at the page HTML in the browser so that you can figure out how controls are rendered (you can press function key F12 in InternetExplorer to view the Developer tools pane, where you can see the HTML tree)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gv_C1All').click(function () {
        $('.col1 > input').attr("checked", $('#gv_C1All').attr("checked"));
        $('.col2 > input').removeAttr("checked");
        $('#gv_C2All').removeAttr("checked");
    });

    $('#gv_C2All').click(function () {
        $('.col2 > input').attr("checked", $('#gv_C2All').attr("checked"));
        $('.col1 > input').removeAttr("checked");
        $('#gv_C1All').removeAttr("checked");
    });

    $('.col1').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var id = $("input", this).attr('id');
            var coresId = id.replace('Approve', 'Reject');
            $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
            $('#gv_C1All').removeAttr("checked");
            $('#gv_C2All').removeAttr("checked");
        });
    });

    $('.col2').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var id = $("input", this).attr('id');
            var coresId = id.replace('Reject', 'Approve');
            $('#' + coresId).removeAttr("checked");
            $('#gv_C1All').removeAttr("checked");
            $('#gv_C2All').removeAttr("checked");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Prashanth, i am learning jquery now... do you know any good site and i know can google get tons of web-site but do you know any one you recommend?

Comment: You don't have to go anywhere; jquery.com itself has plenty of resources. check jqueryui.com for ui related controls. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to play with html/css/jquery. Goodluck