# Selecting all check boxes using header check box in grid of asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

It tried many solutions but nothing worked. Please provide me jquery code to select all check boxes of current page of gridview by checking checkbox in header template. I am using asp.net 4 using c#. Any detailed guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code for your question.

Comment: Without sharing your code, no one will be able to help you. I've already answered a question addressing a similar issue; Have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607199/how-to-make-this-jquery-code-works-with-gridview-control#comment13746483_10607199`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xhj4/6/)

Replace `div.gridview` with the selector for the container of all of the checkboxes in the current page. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
  $('#friendslist').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
 });
});
```

selectall : the id of the checkbox toggler
friendslist : the id of the dom element to search voor checkboxes

Ofcourse, if you want the toggler to react to changes in the other checkboxes you have to add a second piece of jquery to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
  $(':checkbox[id*="checkid"]').attr('checked', this.checked);
 });
```

});

be sure to replace checkid with your asp.net checkbox id in the grid.